# How to do a subtraction between two rows and same column in SQL?

Tags: sql

So let's say I have data like the following

```
Date A B
1/1  3 6
1/2  4 5
1/3  2 7
```

I want to write a query that creates a column C, where C is calculated by A[i] - A[i - 1] + B. For example, for 1/2, column C would equal 4 - 3 + 5 = 6. For 1/3, column C would equal 2 - 4 + 7 = 5. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LAG`:

```
SELECT *, 
   A + B - COALESCE(LAG(A) OVER(ORDER BY Date),0) AS c
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `lag()`:

```
select date, a, b,
       (a + b - lag(a) over (order by date)) as c
from t;
```

This produces `null` in the first row.  If you want to treat the "previous" row as `0` rather than `null`, use the 3-argument form of `lag()`:

```
select date, a, b,
       (a + b - lag(a, 1, 0) over (order by date)) as c
from t;
```

Comment: Is this possible to do when I need to use a case clause? For example, there's actually another column for function names, and I only need to do this for a specific function

Comment: @mumair . . . I believe this answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, please ask it as *another* question.